# How can I send inputs to a URL (someone else's server) and get the output back for use in my PHP?

Tags: php, http

I'm trying to use a free translation server (this is offered by someone else) for my website that returns the translation of what is at the end of the URL. For example typing this url will return a translation in English
http://www.edrdg.org/cgi-bin/wwwjdic/wwwjdic.cgi?1ZUQ%E7%BF%BB%E8%A8%B3

My question is how can I capture the output of this url using html/php/javascript/ajax without having my webpage leave my site.

So far I have tried creating a function which is put into the  tag of my html

```
<script>
    function foo()
    {
        var translation;
        $.get('http://www.edrdg.org/cgi-bin/wwwjdic/wwwjdic.cgi?1ZUQ%E7%BF%BB%E8%A8%B3', function(data)
        {
            translation = data;
        }
    }
</script>
```

and trying to call it like this

```
<div>
    <p><?php echo foo(); ?></p>
</div>
```

To me this looks terrible and doesn't work so my main question is how to capture what that URL gives me and also how can I store that data and display it on my html? Thanks.

Comment: Start here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use JavaScript function from PHP. Of course it won't work. JavaScript is executed in browser and PHP is executed on server.

The easiest way to get data from URL in php is to use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php):

```
 <div>
   <p>
   <?php
     echo file_get_contents('http://www.edrdg.org/cgi-bin/wwwjdic/wwwjdic.cgi?1ZUQ%E7%BF%BB%E8%A8%B3');
   ?>
   </p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`file_get_contents` will work fine for this particular case since the page is just text content, but I'd use a combination of CURL and XPath in the event you want to grab some nodes values without any wrapping html.

**PHP** curl.php

```
<?php
$url  = $_REQUEST['url'];

$curl = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

$html = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);


$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html);
libxml_clear_errors();
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);


// Find stuff
$result = $xpath->query("/html/body/pre");

$data = array();

if (!is_null($result)) {

  foreach ($result as $key => $element) {
    $nodes = $element->nodeValue;

    $data[$key] = $nodes;

  }
}

print_r($data[0]);

?>
```

**JavaScript/jQuery**

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'curl.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        url: 'http://www.edrdg.org/cgi-bin/wwwjdic/wwwjdic.cgi?1ZUQ%E7%BF%BB%E8%A8%B3'
    },
})
.done(function (data) {
    $('body').append(data);
})
.fail(function (data) {
    console.log("error", data);
})
```

Comment: Are there any advantages of this over file_get_contents?

Comment: Just the one I stated at the top of my answer. For this particular use case, not really, since it's just text content. But you can tailor this one for anything really, and much more nested content, not just a big block of text in the body.

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting a DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Empty string supplied as input so I think the curl isn't working. Did I need to create a curl.php to activate the ajax?

Comment: Yes, the PHP should be in a separate file called curl.php. Also make sure you have curl installed. You could however just use @Konstantin's answer - it will work fine.

Comment: I created the curl.php and there are no errors now. I'm pretty sure I have curl since Nordenheim's answer is working but the output still isn't on my webpage. Does this ajax just append it to my <body> tag or is it in the POST variable? EDIT: figured out how to see the characters properly using encoding utf-8